# Battery Drains on Suspend - Ubuntu 18.04 - ASUS Vivobook 15

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management, asus, battery

The battery drains fully on suspension for Ubuntu 18.04 on my ASUS Vivobook 15. This is telling me that I'm not actually going into suspension. What am I missing?

One of the solutions suggested was to do the following steps:

> I found out that you need add mem_sleep_default=deep to the Kernel
> boot parameter:
>
> - Open the GRUB file: sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
> - Find the line: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
> - Replace it by: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep"
> - Update GRUB file: sudo update-grub

I have completed those steps, however upon waking my laptop from suspension, I found that it was drained of all of its battery. This is not a case of a bad battery either, as this device is dual-booted with Windows 11 and I do not run into this issue when using Windows 11.

Any reasons for why this may be happening?

Comment: What happens when you hibernate instead of suspend?

Comment: @J-Cake It looks like hibernating shaves off about 2% of charge after 10 minutes. Is this expecting from hibernation?

Comment: Hibernation is the computer completely shut down. In an ideal situation, your computer should not lose any power whatsoever. But given that it does, even while shut down, I suspect it to be a hardware issue, as what happens after shutdown is beyond the control of the operating system. Mind me asking how old the computer/battery is?

Comment: @J-Cake The computer is about a year old after purchase along with the battery. However, these issues aren't persistent with my Windows boot, so could this be attributed to Ubuntu?

Comment: In my case, it didn't help at all, but you could try killing the upower service, and seeing what happens. Don't worry, this is a completely non-destructive action, and will be running again at next boot. 
```systemctl stop upower```